# EF Core Get DBSet by string then use it on a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to make a tool that enables a user to select tables/columns from a ui. When the user posts the "query configuration object" to the server, I want to create a dynamic **SQL Query using Entity Framework Core**

*Example*

Given `var tableName = "Table1";`

I want to grab the `DbSet<tableName>` and then run something like

```
var dbSet = GetDbSet("Table1");
var stuff = await dbSet.Take(10).ToListAsync();
```

I'm sure this is possible in some shape/form but all the articles I'm seeing are similar in the approach. Everything compiles, but when I run it, I get `Object Refeerence not set to an instance of an object` fun.

Here's what I have:

```
var select = GetDbSet(tableName);
var results = await select.Take(10).ToListAsync();
```

The **GetDbSet** method:

*This works obviously* But, I need to variablize the `T` (which I can't do??)

```
    private DbSet<Table1> GetDbSet(string name)
    {
        return _dbContext.Set<Table1>();
    }
```

From what I've read, I created an extension method since I need `Set(T)` and not `Set<T>()`

```
        public static IQueryable<object> Set(this DbContext _context, Type t)
        {
            return (IQueryable<object>) _context.GetType().GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(_context, null);
        }
```

This does what I *think* I'm expecting it to:

```
    private IQueryable GetDbSet(string name)
    {
        // forcing a type instead of fiddling with the string for simplicity
        return _dbContext.Set(_dbContext.Table1.GetType());
    }
```

But, this code won't compile:

```
var select = GetDbSet(tableName);
var results = await select.Take(10).ToListAsync();
```

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Take' and no
>   accessible extension method 'Take' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Am I even on the right path for grabbing a `DbSet` and using it to query? Do I need to build extension methods for `Take`, and any other methods I want to use?

Comment: Do you have a `using System.Linq;`? That's where `Take`  and some other extension methods come from.

Comment: Why are you building your own non-generic Set method if there is one already?

Comment: @Gleb There is not. There is only Set<T> in EF Core 3.0

Comment: FWIW: I gave up with EF for this use case. I found SqlKata(https://sqlkata.com/) which (at the moment) seems to be far more capable with a much greater ease-of-use for building dynamic queries. I don't get the feeling EF Core wants you to do this type of thing.